# Copied a varchar(max) field to its own table, but the new table is significantly bigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data table with 24 fields, one of which is a `varchar(max)` in my SQL Server 2012 DB. I'm attempting to move the `varchar(max)` field to its own table, so I've created a new table with two fields, the `varchar(max)` and the ID of the row in the initial table. The `Varchar(max)` is only populated about three quarters of the time, so the new table has a smaller row count than the source. The new table has been populated with an "`Insert into.... Select`" statement

In terms of data space used, my new table is 30% larger than the source table, even though it only contains 75% of the rows and 10% of the fields. I can't see any differences in the field definitions or coalition, so I'm struggling to understand how it can be so much larger

Are there any other factors here that I need to consider?

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not _fields_.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that using a SELECT INTO table with a varchar(max) field will force SQL Server to allocate one 8K page per row no matter if you have data in the column or not.  Therefore even the rows that have no data will need space allocated.  The better option would be to use CREATE TABLE/ INSERT INTO.  See the example below:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (ID int, testdata varchar(max))
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(1,'test'),(2, 'test2'),(3,'again')

CREATE TABLE tblTest1(ID int, testdata varchar(max))
INSERT INTO tblTest1 SELECT ID, testdata from #tmp
SELECT ID, testdata into tblTest3 from #tmp


exec sp_spaceused tblTEst1
exec sp_spaceused tblTEst3
```

> ```
> name        rows  reserved    data    index_size  unused
>
> tblTest1     3      16 KB     8 KB      8 KB       0 KB
>
> tblTest3     3      32 KB     24 KB     8 KB       0 KB
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I built my table using an Insert.....select, not a select....into